# Rails View doesn't update until refreshed but controller is updating database fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

This is the first time I've encountered this problem.

I have a view which submits a post request to a controller which updates two tables.

```
def update
  if request.post?
    if @circuit
      # update
      @circuit.update_attributes params[:circuit]

      @logical_interface = LogicalInterface.new params[:logical_interface]
      @logical_interface.save


      #redirect_to :action => 'update', :id => @circuit.id
      @success = "Updated." if @circuit.valid?
    else
      # attempt create
    end
  end
end
```

These three lines are what I've added to the controller:

```
@logical_interface = LogicalInterface.new params[:logical_interface]
@logical_interface.save


redirect_to :action => 'update', :id => @circuit.id # this was added because the view wasn't being updated until refreshed
```

If I keep the redirect, the view will be updated accordingly but I get no `Updated.` message in the `@success` variable.

If I comment out the redirect, the `circuit` form fields at the top of my form will update but not the table of `logical_interfaces` that I am adding to but I still get the `Updated.` success message. Everything is in the view directly, no partials are used.

Hopefully I've explained it properly but if anyone is unsure then I can update the question to go into more detail.

The form is just:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => "circuit", :action => "update" %>
    ...
</form>
```

In the form I use two objects `circuit` and `logical_interface` to split up the inputs so that in the controller I can update the `circuit` and create a new `logical_interface`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to adjust positions of redirect_to and @success, I think redirect_to should be the last line of the block.

And If you use redirect_to, you will lose all your instance variables, so better way is using flash.

in your controller:

```
flash[:notice] = "Updated." if @circuit.valid?    
redirect_to :action => 'update', :id => @circuit.id
```

in your page:

```
<p><%= flash[:notice]%></p>
```

Comment: thanks, I did try that but with this the page will update fine but I get no success message.